# Нужна ли запятая после слова "например"?

Tags: пунктуация

"Некоторые возражали, но не очень, например Иван Федорович, не желавший перечить Настасье Филипповне и заметивший, как увлекает ее эта странная мысль".

Поясните, пожалуйста. Мне казалось, что оно всегда обособляется..

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Здесь запятая после НАПРИМЕР не нужна, так как вводное слово стоит в начале обособленной уточняющей конструкции. Если вводное слово стоит в начале или в конце обособленной конструкции, запятая не ставится.

ПАС Лопатина:
§ 93. Если вводное слово или вводное сочетание слов стоит в начале или в конце обособленного члена предложения, то оно не отделяется от него знаком препинания, т. е. запятые выделяют член предложения вместе с вводным словом:
1) В одну ночь, должно быть из озорства, списком был оклеен фасад городской думы (Фад.), ср.: Около самой черной тучи летали перекати-поле, и как, должно быть, им было страшно (Ч.); 
К автобусу подошла девочка, по сути ребенок, ср.: После этого, по сути, и спрашивать об ее [Аксиньи] отношениях к Григорию было незачем (Шол.); Студент вернул в библиотеку книгу, вероятно даже не прочитав ее, ср.: Небо потемнело. Скоро, вероятно, пойдет дождь; Дана достаточно ясная характеристика, в частности декабриста Михаила Спиридова (Чив.), ср. На собрании вопрос, в частности, касался методов обучения; Что же касается русских серьезных статей, например по социологии, по искусству и проч., то я не читаю их просто из робости (Ч.)